# Допустимо ли такое уточнение?

Tags: уточнения

За 25 лет, методом проб, проверялась эффективность различных моделей (повышение, понижение цен, предоставление определенных бонусов).

Answer (score 1):

**Внесены правильные изменения**, но лучше оставить **И.п.**: В течение 25 лет методом проб проверялась эффективность различных моделей (повышение и понижение цен, предоставление определенных бонусов).

Вставная конструкция грамматически не связана с предложением, а смысл и так понятен.

Comment: Спасибо большое.

Answer (score 0):

В течение 25 лет методом проб проверялась эффективность различных моделей (повышения и понижения цен, предоставления определенных бонусов).

Перечисление надо просклонять, т.к. они имеют отношение к слову *модели*, а не *эффективность*. Запятые (в начале фразы) лишние. Остальное — дело вкуса.

Comment: Спасибо большое.